# Migrate Access mde app and Microsoft Sql Database to another PC

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I need to move an old Access app, which runs on a windows server 2003, to my Windows 10 PC,
The app is run from the Server desktop via mde file and is connected to a microsoft SQLEXPRESS database installed locally on the server,
I installed locally on my pc windows 10 Microsoft Sql express, and changed the hostname of my PC setting "SERVER".

I can access the tables and the database seems to work, but when I launch the "example.mde" file from my computer the application fails and cannot find the database asking me for the path..

if i click continue with trusted authentication it ask me again for every move i make .. I don't know how to specify the data source or connection string for the database on the new machine, I believe this is about the ODBC driver,
attached the error I get
Thanks in advance for the help[image]

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: Ask your question on Stack Overflow or Super User